# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Gibt es eine vollständige Liste von Adjektiven, die einen Umlaut im Komparativ und Superlativ haben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20762/gibt-es-eine-vollst%c3%a4ndige-liste-von-adjektiven-die-einen-umlaut-im-komparativ-u)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Explaining the adjective ending in “zum ersten Mal”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20615/explaining-the-adjective-ending-in-zum-ersten-mal)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to say "Sorry, not now, I am too busy"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20472/how-to-say-sorry-not-now-i-am-too-busy)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Rationale for the compound adjective "US-amerikanisch"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20669/rationale-for-the-compound-adjective-us-amerikanisch)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Welche Benennungsschemata für die verschiedenen Konjunktivformen gibt es und wie funktionieren sie?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/welche-benennungsschemata-f%c3%bcr-die-verschiedenen-konjunktivformen-gibt-es-und-wie)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Warum "unter der Brücke hindurchgehen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/warum-unter-der-br%c3%bccke-hindurchgehen)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What is more common "von Mal zu Mal" or "Mal für Mal"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20451/what-is-more-common-von-mal-zu-mal-or-mal-f%c3%bcr-mal)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Is the name Goebbels somehow exceptional?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/is-the-name-goebbels-somehow-exceptional)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Meaning of "Einpreßrate" or "Einpreßmenge"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20548/meaning-of-einpre%c3%9frate-or-einpre%c3%9fmenge)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to pronounce the German R?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20831/how-to-pronounce-the-german-r)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

Answer (score 2):

When voting, please note the criteria:

> Run comparative Google searches on these questions and see if the content is better or worse than what is already out there on the internet. Are the answers correct, clear, useful and informative? Would the question and answer be interesting to the kind of user this site is trying to attract? Choose:
>
> **Excellent** if this question is well written and has a clear, comprehensive answer that is far better than other available resources. This question shows up early in search results.
>
> **Satisfactory** if this question has a clear, comprehensive answer that is comparable or better than the information found elsewhere. This question shows up later in the search results or requires oddly specific search terms to find.
>
> **Needs Improvement** if this question is poorly written, not generally useful, or has an answer that is no better than what can be found elsewhere. Alternatively, this question does not turn up on the first page or two in Google despite repeated search attempts.
>
> **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next question